# Fixed bar width for chartjs 2.x

Tags: charts, bar-chart

I am creating some bar charts with chartjs 2.x

Looking for the fixed bar width option along with chartjs 2.x, now its adjusting according to the bar count. Found a option like "barPercentage", but it's not fit for me because it's work like percentage on each chart. I found one similar question about chartjs 1.x, but its chartjs 2.x

Answer (score 1):

I got a custom function to achieve this functionality. I hope it might be help someone else.

Step1: Update the functionality "calculateBarWidth" in the core(Chart.js) like below.

```
calculateBarWidth: function(index) {
        var xScale = this.getScaleForId(this.getMeta().xAxisID);

        if (xScale.options.fixBarWidth) {
            return xScale.options.fixedBarWidth;
        }

        var ruler = this.getRuler(index);
        return xScale.options.stacked ? ruler.categoryWidth : ruler.barWidth;
    }
```

Step2: Also add some custom properties(fixBarWidth, fixedBarWidth) in the initialization part.

```
var options = {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
                // Manually set bar width in pixels
                fixBarWidth: true,
                fixedBarWidth: 10
            }]
          }
        }
```